# Using the same activity for different buttons but different action using xml resource

Tags: android

I am doing a project in Android Studio. I will have 2/3 activities at most. On main activity I will have some buttons. There will be a second activity. So for each button that second activity will pop up and show some more buttons or imageButton but they will be different. The buttons on the second activity will also be meant for different actions but all of it will be on a third activity. The third activity will have some images and a text view. So image view and text view will show different data from the "XML resource" for different buttons. Any ideas how I can do it?I am using Android Studio.

Can it be done using base Adapter?

Also when all the data are stored on sql database, what different thing do I need to do?

Thank You!

Comment: did you tried using fragments?

Answer (score 0):

When you go from main activity to the second activity, you must be using intent.
You can add extra info in your intent to to modify accordingly using putExtra()

Then in your second activity, you can simply retrieve the extra info and make changes accordingly.

in main activity,

```
//your first button
    Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent newintent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        newintent.putExtra("details", "load first set of images");
        startActivity(newintent);
        }
    });
//your second button
    Button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent newintent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        newintent.putExtra("details", "load second set of images");
        startActivity(newintent);
        }
    });
```

in second activity,

```
 String extrainfo=getIntent().getStringExtra("details");
 if(extrainfo.equals("load first set of images"))
{
//make your changes accordingly
}
else if(extrainfo.equals("load second set of images"))
{
//make your changes accordingly
}
else
{
//make according changes
}
```

This is how you can achieve it.
Hope this helps!

Comment: That was really helpful. Thank You. I just had a thought. For each button I would like to show a listView of set of items. So through the intent I want to pass data so that I can have different listViews for each button but on the same activity. Can this be done? Thank You.